# Android version compatibility

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet, 4.3-jelly-bean

I would like to know a tablet with following specifications support Android 4.3 (or 4.2 or 4.1)? It currently runs on 4.0.4.

Specifications Summary:

```
DISPLAY (800x444)
    Size: 800x444
    Refresh Rate: 59.69 Hz
    Density: 120 dpi (Low)

PROCESSOR (ARMv7)
    Processor: ARMv7 Processor rev 2 (v7l)
    Cores: 1
    Max Frequency: 1008 Mhz
    Instruction Sets: armeabi-v7a, armeabi
    SIMD Instructions: NEON

MEMORY (353 MB)
    System RAM: 353 MB
    JVM Max Memory: 48 MB
    Internal Storage: 617 MB
    External Storage: 3785 MB

OPENGL 1.X (Mali-400 MP)
OPENGL 2.0 (Mali-400 MP)
GRAPHIC MODES (RGBA 32bit)
GRAPHICS
    OpenGL 2.0
```

Full details of spec is available here : https://gist.github.com/abidrahmank/6913200

Comment: Is this a shopping question or do you like to know how to upgrade your device to 4.3?

Comment: I already have the tablet. I need to upgrade it to 4.3. Its manufacturers don't release any update. So I need to check if it can afford 4.3 or any version after 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

353MB is probably too little for a proper 4.1+ experience.

Besides this, there's no generic Android installation media, each device needs its firmware tailored and adapted by the manufacturer. If the manufacturer has put it end-of-life, you're hosed unless you find someone who ported it or you port it yourself.

Comment: OK, so I will have to stay with what I have. Anyway Thank you for the help +1

Comment: Remaining option: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device